# Call from MDB to SSB is always anonymous in JBoss AS7/EAP6

Tags: jboss7.x, jaas, jboss-eap-6

Got problem with JBoss AS7 / EAP6. In MDB, when I lookup for SSB and call its method, the call is always anonymous, i.e. `sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()` returns Principal(anonymous). Always... In AS5 everything was fine.

How can I fix it to make a call with an authenticated user?

My MDB:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/piQueue"), 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "dLQMaxResent", propertyValue = "3")
})
@SecurityDomain("mySecurityDomain")
public class PIMessageBean implements MessageListener {
...
    **//subject always anonymous...**
    Subject subject = (Subject) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");

    PIManager pim = lookupPIManager();
    pim.getPIs(); **//call is anonymous**
...
}
```

My queue settings:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.2">
    <hornetq-server>
    ...
        <jms-destinations>
            <jms-queue name="piQueue">
                <entry name="queue/piQueue"/>
                <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/piQueue"/>
            </jms-queue>
        </jms-destinations>
        <security-domain>mySecurityDomain</security-domain>
    </hornetq-server>
</subsystem>
```

My Security Domain:

```
<security-domain name="mySecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.qu.vad.CustomUsernamePasswordLoginModule" flag="required">
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by doing JAAS login in MDB